# How to create PCRE-pattern that matches only when there is 2 character

Tags: php, regex, url-routing

I'm currently trying to create SEO-friendly URL's. Because of that I have created the following regular expression. What I want is to lead to another URL when the URL is e.g.:

```
da/something/something-else.html => 'da/pages/view/something/something-else'
something/something-else.html => 'pages/view/something/something-else'
something => 'pages/view/something'
```

I have created this regular expression:

```
'/(([a-z][^\/])(1))(?:(\/))([^.]+)\.html/' => '$1$2pages/view/$3/'
```

What is needed is, that the first part HAS TO BE 2 CHARACTER LONG - if it is not, then it isn't a language-tag and shouldn't be passed. Then the rest just has to NOT have . (dot) inside (because of the ".html" part).

Is this possible??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a try with :

```
$arr = array('da/something/something-else.html', 'something/something-else.html', 'something');
foreach ($arr as $str) {
    echo $str,' => ';
    $str = preg_replace("~^([a-z]{2}/|)([^.]*)(?:\.html)?$~", "$1pages/view/$2", $str);
    echo $str,"\n";
}
```

**output:**

```
da/something/something-else.html => da/pages/view/something/something-else
something/something-else.html => pages/view/something/something-else
something => pages/view/something
```

explanation could be viewed [here](http://chris.photobooks.com/regex/default.htm)

Comment: +1 This will work. However `[^.]*?` doesn't need to be non-greedy. It can very well be `[^.]*`

Comment: Well I have to have a static bit (the .html-part) as the rest of the framework is running with "the normal" url-routing. This means that I explode by "/" and then the first part is the controller, the second part is the action and the third, fourth and (n)th part is the querystring (parameters).

Do you have a solution so I can still have this? Currently I have this array:

$routing = array(
 '/error\/([0-9]+)/' => 'error/error_\2',
 '~^([a-z]{2}/|)([^.]*):\.html?$~' => '$1pages/view/$2/'
);

Comment: @Dennis Lauritzen: I don't understand what are your needs. May you edit your question to explain more or create a new question with some examples ?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't tested it but you can add the restriction to your expression this way:

```
'#^/[a-z]{2}/(([a-z][^\/])(1))(?:(\/))([^.]+)\.html#' => '$1$2pages/view/$3/'
```

^/[a-z]{2}/ will force to have 2 [a-z] in the beginning (^) of the line.

I have changed the delimiter from / to # so you don't need to escape the /.

ps. Language codes can have more than 2 letters if they contain the region modifier: pt_BR, pt_PT and en_US.

Comment: @Dennis See http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your subject text is always a relative URL, this should do it:

```
$re = '%^([A-Za-z]{2}/)?(.*?)(\.html)?%i';
$url = preg_replace($re, '$1pages/view/$2', $url);
```

**Edit:** Fixed to remove optional `.html` extension.

Comment: this doesn't delete `.html` as OP wants